# OctopusPublishPackageToHttp in TFS Service

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am trying to get my build configured in the TFS Service to deploy my .nuget package to my private,hosted nuGet server.

I am using NuGet.Server.v2.2.31210.9045 for my nuGet Server.

The build successfully creates the nuget package via OctoPack.

I can push to my nuGet repository with the following command (dummied up some values):

nuget push AppyThingy.1.0.4816.37140.nupkg -s http://nuget.myserver.com:1601 01414ad3-3e0c-4ba4-9dae-04e62ff4d0f0

That works swimmingly!

I added the following to my build definition's MSBuild Arguments parameter:

/p:OctopusPublishPackageToHttp=http://nuget.myserver.com:1601 /p:OctopusPublishApiKey=01414ad3-3e0c-4ba4-9dae-04e62ff4d0f0

This doesn't work.  I don't why it doesn't work.  I don't see any log info that helps me nail down the issue.  I have tried mucking with the http but I am just shooting in the dark.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The walkthrough on Paul's website for TFS Service is incorrect. It looks like the latest version of OctoPack changed those params to OctoPack and not Octopus. It is now working.