# How do I deploy my nuget package with Octopus Deploy and TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, octopus-deploy

I am attempting to fully automate the deployment of a simple assembly onto two application servers (which have the Tentacle services installed), and I'm running into a few challenges.

**What I have achieved:**

I *can* create a NuGet package with /p:RunOctoPack=true.
I *can* manually upload (publish?) the package to my built-in feed on the Octopus Deploy server.
I *can* deploy the packages to both my application servers using the Octopus Deploy portal.

I can infer from the post ([OctopusPublishPackageToHttp in TFS Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316115/octopuspublishpackagetohttp-in-tfs-service/15319277#15319277)) that I should be able simply put all of the following on the Process/Build/Advanced/MSBuild Arguments box

> /p:RunOctoPack=true
>   /p:OctopusPublishPackageToHttp=http://octoserver:8081/nuget/packages
>   /p:OctopusPublishApiKey=API-MYKEY.

**However my builds are returning the error**

> Exception Message: Access to the path 'C:\Builds\1\Experiments\CIBuildDef\bin\ConsoleTibcoMefClient1.1.0.0.0.nupkg' is denied.
>   (type UnauthorizedAccessException)

With this assembly (a simple .NET Class Library). The builds are all being dropped into the same path (C:\Builds\1\Experiments\CIBuildDef\bin). I'm accustomed to a new folder being created by the build every time. I must be missing something in the build definition settings. Am I getting this error because I'm not changing the version number of the package yet? I cannot seem to delete the nupkg that was originally dropped in the Builds directory, even after deleting it from the feed.

How do put my NuGet package onto the feed with TFS?
How do run my Octopus Deploy steps from TFS?
Am I asking the right questions?

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your drop folder path? ''CBuilds\1\..." is suspicious. Shouldn't it be "C:\Builds\1\..."?

Comment: That was a typo. I have now corrected the Exception Message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you ping your octopus server from tfs build server? And could you telnet to 8081 port from your tfs build server? If you could, you should rebuild the project not build for the same repository. If the new nuget version is not higher than 1.0.0.0 octopack could fail. You must increment the nuget version from your tfs build template. The following commands must be work for you. This commands are for msdeploy deployment with powershell. If you want to use msdeploy you must install it to tentacles. I am using it for web project deployment.
Command line arguments:

```
/t:Rebuild /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False 
/p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None /p:IsAutoBuild=True 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageLocation=".\obj\Release\Myproject.zip";PackageAsSingleFile=True /p:RunOctoPack=true 
/p:OctoPackPackageVersion=%VERSION%-dev 
/p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://octopus.yourdomain.com/nuget/packages /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=API-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: I had forgotten that I had asked this question. When I modified the build template (months ago) to change the version number, it started working.